# How to stop the Api icon keep adding when click the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I have to create a web with two buttons to show each city's information.
When I clicked the button the icon would keep adding every each time i click it.
I have tried if statement also but it did not work. is there any ways can stop it or other method to show the icon?

```js
window.onload=function(){
 
  var chooseBox = document.getElementById("output");
  var tempOut = document.getElementById("temperature");
  var condiOut = document.getElementById("conditions");
  var locationOut = document.getElementById("location");
  var weaIcon = document.getElementById("icon");
  var torontBtn = document.getElementById("Toronto");
  var tpeBtn = document.getElementById("Taipei");
  var feelstemp = document.getElementById("feelsLike");

  const myApiKey = "0730ce4dd97d237ff76898a994164939";
  const toUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto&appid=" + myApiKey + "&units=metric";
  const tpeUrl ="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Taipei&appid=" + myApiKey + "&units=metric";

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ){
      if ( xhr.status === 200){
        const data = xhr.response;
        console.log(data);

        const iconWea =  "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";

        var elementIcon = document.createElement('img');
        elementIcon.setAttribute('src', iconWea);
        
        weaIcon.appendChild(elementIcon); //SHOWASSIGNED ICON
        locationOut.innerHTML = data.name;
        tempOut.innerHTML = data.main.temp + "°C" ;
        feelstemp.innerHTML = data.main.feels_like + "°C" ;
        condiOut.innerHTML = data.weather[0].description;
      } else {
        locationOut.innerHTML = "API call was unsucessful";
        console.log(xhr.status);
      }
    }
  }
  torontBtn.onclick = function() { 
    chooseBox.style.display = "block";
    xhr.open('GET',toUrl,true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.send(null);
  }  
  tpeBtn.onclick = function () { 
    chooseBox.style.display = "block";
    xhr.open('GET',tpeUrl,true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.send(null);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
var iconUrl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + data.weather[0].icon + "@2x.png";
out_icon.innerHTML = `<img src='${iconUrl}'/>`;
```

Comment: this works. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

weaIcon.appendChild(elementIcon) should be replaced with weaIcon.innerHtml=elementIcon